# Connection refused when trying to access containerized PostgreSQL

Tags: java, database, postgresql, containers, podman

My setup is a Podman pod with PostgreSQL and pgAdmin that I created with these commands:

```
podman pod create --name postgre-sql -p 9876:80
podman run --name postgresql --pod postgre-sql -d -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin docker.io/library/postgres
podman run --name pgadmin --pod postgre-sql -d -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@mail.com' -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin' docker.io/dpage/pgadmin4
```

Pod ran with no errors, I can enter pgAdmin, connect to the PostgreSQL container and configure my databases without a problem but when I try to connnect with a database on Java I get the following error message:

> Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port
> are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

I've tried with these URL and none works (driver is correctly installed):

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9876/db
```

I've tried the solutions on other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60730020/postgresql-refuses-connection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912298/postgres-connection-refused) and none works for me.

Comment: Is your java code running inside the container like pgadmin is? If not, then you don't have any postgresql port forwarding defined for your pod - route something to 5432 inside the pod.

Comment: @RichardHuxton That worked, thanks. Can you write it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?